# How is Find my iPhone still working even when phone is turned off?

Tags: find-my-iphone

My iPhone was stolen a few days ago and goes straight to voicemail when called, but still updates its location on Find my iPhone. Bottom line question is how is this possible if it is supposedly "offline"?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it's out of cellular reception (or has had the SIM card removed) but has an active data connection through WiFi.